# Missing component in a kernel module with several source files

Tags: module, linker, linux-kernel

I had a little module with a single C source file `foo.c`, and all was well.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
static int __init foo_init(void) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "foo_init says hello (%d)\n");
        return 0;
}
static void __exit foo_exit(void) {
}
module_init(foo_init);
module_exit(foo_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("ACME");
```

The `Makefile` was simple:

```
obj-m += foo.o
```

Now that the source has grown, I want to add a second source file `bar.c`:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
int aux(int x) {
        return x + 1;
}
```

I've added a call to the `aux` function in `foo.c`. (Well, in real life I declare the `aux` function in a header, and my code does more than print a message, but I've shrunk my problem to this small example.) And I've added a line to declare the components of the module in the makefile, following [`Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt).

```
foo-objs += bar.o
obj-m += foo.o
```

But now, when I build the module, it seems that `foo.o` is not linked (`modinfo` reports no module license and author, `nm foo.ko` doesn't find the symbols defined in `foo.c`, `foo_init` is evidently not run when I load the module). Putting `foo-objs := foo.o bar.o` in the makefile doesn't help.

Why does adding a second source file displace the first source file, and how do I get `foo` back?

In case this matters: the kernel version is 2.6.35, the architecture is arm, and the module is in-tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get your thing to compile, I'd suggest renaming `foo.c` to e.g. `foo-base.c` (the idea being not to have a `.c` file with the same name as the module. The `foo-objs` will build `foo.o` from the other objects you specify but *not* from `foo.c`).

Then you can do:

```
foo-objs := foo-base.o bar.o
obj-m += foo.o
```

(`foo-y := ...` works too, but the Makefiles I've looked at use the `-objs` version.)
And it should work:

```
$ modprobe foo
$ dmesg|tail
...
[ 8375.303738] foo_init says hello (100)
$ modinfo foo
filename:       /lib/modules/3.0.3-gentoo/kernel/drivers/usb/test/foo.ko
author:         ACME
license:        GPL
depends:        
vermagic:       3.0.3-gentoo SMP mod_unload
```

[that is, after you've given enough arguments to `printk` in your sample :-)]

Note: don't forget to clean up all the generated files before rebuilding your module after that change.

Comment: Thanks, I found it eventually (I wrote an answer explaining how — writing a tiny example to ask the question was 90% of solving the problem). The issue is indeed having a source file with the same name as the module.

Answer (score 1):

Shrinking down to a small example was 90% of solving this. It let me see that, with `foo-objs := foo.o bar.o` in the makefile, `make` complains:

```
make[1]: Circular z/foo.o <- z/foo.o dependency dropped.
```

The trouble is harder to detect with `foo-objs += bar.o`, but it's hidden in the output from `make V=1`:

```
ld -EL    -r -o z/foo.o z/bar.o
```

What's going on under the hood is that `$(module_name).o` is part of the build chain for `$(module_name).ko`. Each source file `%.c` is compiled to `%.o`. If there's a source file with the same base name as the module, the same file name has two purposes and havoc ensues. In the special case where there's a single source file, `$(module_name).o` is supposed to be identical to `$(source_file).o` anyway, so the build chain comes out right.

If a module has more than one source file, the module name must be distinct from the name of any source file.

I renamed `foo.c` to `foo_main.c` and all is well.